# Fullcalendar not showing events properly in dayGrid or week view

Tags: fullcalendar

Im trying to create events with a range of time, but when i go to day or week view they show really weird. I have read a lot of questions but I couldnt fix it. I tried with allDay set to false, but the problem is not there.

I did download the library again. I also did disable all the css (except bootstrap), but the problem is still there.

```
    let calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

    let calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        aspectRatio: 2,
        plugins: [ 'dayGrid', 'interaction', 'timeGrid' ],
        allDayDefault: false,
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true,
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        locale: 'es',
        header: {
            left: "prev,next",
            center: "title",
            right: "dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek"
        },
        events:[
            {
            title: 'All Day Event',
            start: '2019-08-01',
            },
            {
            title: 'Long Event',
            start: '2019-08-07',
            end: '2019-08-10'
            },
            {
            groupId: 999,
            title: 'Repeating Event',
            start: '2019-08-09T16:00:00'
            },
            {
            groupId: 999,
            title: 'Repeating Event',
            start: '2019-08-16T16:00:00'
            },
            {
            title: 'Conference',
            start: '2019-08-11',
            end: '2019-08-13'
            },
            {
            title: 'Meeting',
            start: '2019-08-12T10:30:00',
            end: '2019-08-12T12:30:00'
            },
            {
            title: 'Lunch',
            start: '2019-08-12T12:00:00'
            },
            {
            title: 'Meeting',
            start: '2019-08-12T14:30:00'
            },
            {
            title: 'Happy Hour',
            start: '2019-08-12T17:30:00'
            },
            {
            title: 'Dinner',
            start: '2019-08-12T20:00:00'
            },
            {
            title: 'Birthday Party',
            start: '2019-08-13T07:00:00'
            },
            {
            title: 'Click for Google',
            url: 'http://google.com/',
            start: '2019-08-28'
            }
        ]});

    calendar.render();
    calendar.updateSize();
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijz04.jpg

Comment: Solved, I forgot to add the css related to timegrid and list.

<link href='fullcalendar/daygrid/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href="fullcalendar/list/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="fullcalendar/timegrid/main.css" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: if there's no longer an issue, please just delete the question, thanks